# Convergence of $\sum_{n} \frac{e^{nw}}{(1+in)^3}$ and $\sum_{n} \frac{1}{1+e^{i \pi \theta n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

I wish to determine whether the following two series converge:

1. *Series #1:*$$\sum_{n} \frac{e^{nw}}{(1+in)^3},$$
   where $w \in \mathbb{C}$ is fixed.

- To determine the convergence, I use the ratio test: $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left|\frac{e^{(n+1)w}}{(1+i(n+1))^3} \frac{(1+in)^3}{e^{nw}}\right| = |e^w| <1.$$
- Accordingly, for absolute convergence, I require $|e^w| = |e^{x+iy}| = e^x < 1 \Rightarrow x < 0.$
- I know the series diverges when $x > 0$.
- Lastly, I must investigate the series when $e^{w} = 1$, i.e., $x = 0$. In this case, I get $\sum_{n} \frac{e^{niy}}{(1+in)^3}.$  In absolute value, this produces the series
  $$\sum_{n} \frac{1}{|1+in|^3} = \sum_{n} \frac{1}{(1+n^2)^\frac{3}{2}},$$
  which converges by the Limit Comparison Test (with the $p$-series $\sum 1/n^3$). As the series converges absolutely, it must converge.
- Altogether, I conclude the series converges when $Re(w) \leq 0.$

2. *Series #2:*

$$\sum_{n} \frac{1}{1+e^{i \pi \theta n}},$$
where $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ fixed.

- If $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$, the limit $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} e^{i \pi \theta n}$$ DNE, because the values of the sequence  $\{e^{i \pi \theta n}\}_n$ simply go around on a unit circle in the complex plane, without converging to any number. Accordingly, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}  \frac{1}{1+e^{i \pi \theta n}}$ DNE. As it is not equal to zero, we conclude the series must diverge.

Would my line of reasoning for both series be correct?

Comment: You are absolutely correct.  For the second series it is probably easier to say that the absolute value of  each term is not smaller then $1/2$.